# Unable to equally align items in a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In my app I'm having a `RecyclerView item.xml` here I'm trying to align all items with linear layout but here problem is that when I set width of `TextView` to `wrap_content` if the text being set is too large it pushes out the other items inside the layout and makes them sometimes too small or sometimes they're completely pushed out of the layout here is my XML code which I'm using any help will be appreciated.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/songitemly"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgscov"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgscov"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FCFAFA"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sartist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#D3D1D1"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/playinganim"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_fileName="playing.json"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sname"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgmenu"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playinganim"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dots_vertical_black_48dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Screenshot of recycler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccUvp.jpg)

This is my code after setting width and height to 0dp:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/songitemly"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgscov"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#FCFAFA"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sartist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#D3D1D1"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/playinganim"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_fileName="playing.json"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sname"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgmenu"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playinganim"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dots_vertical_black_48dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use _weight_ for it

Comment: Tried assigning weights too but still if the text being set is too long it pushes out my other items out of the layout and there size is changed to too small like 5dp even if size is set to 25dp

Comment: what is your expected output??

Comment: When you use weight with horizontal layout `width` must be `0dp` and for vertical layout `height` must be `0dp`

Comment: @Piyush it didn't work setting width to 0dp make my textview invisible

Comment: I added my code edited with your code

Comment: Try this if it's work for you!

Comment: @RuchiPatel Show updated code

Comment: @Piyush updated my question please check

Comment: There is no weight being used in updated code. Also do you want to apply equal width to TextView's ?

Comment: I posted my code with some editing may be it's work for you! @RuchiPatel

Comment: @Piyush answer from dinesh did it for me it's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/songitemly"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgscov"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/a" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/buttons"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#FCFAFA"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="Test" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sartist"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#D3D1D1"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                    tools:text="Test" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/buttons"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                    android:id="@+id/playinganim"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="20"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                    app:lottie_fileName="playing.json"
                    app:lottie_loop="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgmenu"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/a" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Leave commit if any issue!

Comment: Still having issue?

Comment: No my issue pertaining to this question is resolved thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height/width as `0dp` (depending on LinearLayout's orientation vertical/horizontal respectively) along with setting it's weight to match it with the constraints, i.e,

```
android:layout_width = "0dp"
android:layout_weight = "1.0"
```

Also, you can use the following for showing ellipses when text is too long :

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: didn't work after setting width to 0dp textview has became invisible

Comment: if your LinearLayout orientation is horizontal, set width as 0dp, else if your orientation is vertical, set height as 0dp